# How to show only train/subway stations using nearby stations api?

Tags: here-api

I am using the nearby stations by geocode transit api to return a json result of 3 closest stations.  I assumed these would be train/subway stations but the 3 closest to any given dynamic lat & lng are usually bus stations.

Example of my query with parameters: https://transit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=LAT%2CLNG&radius=350&app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE&max=3`

I have read in pervious posts that the ability to use modes such as mode=1 is only available whilst using one of the routing apis.

To cut down on API calls, I do not wish to call google map nearby places api for train/stations and then use those stations in another api call to Here.com to get the distances.  I was hoping there was a way I can do it in one call.

I am client side filtering at the moment and only displaying name & distance.  I see that if I change my max parameter to 50, i see more results further down which are tube/subway stations but unsure as to how I would go about filtering these out.  Also, i see reference to icons but no url's given to access them, where are these located?

I am using ReactJS and the native fetch method for my api request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have 3 requirements:
1) names and distances of stations around a specific coordinate, 2) stations should be filtered by only trains/trams(intercity or intracity) and 
doesn't include buses and remaining other modes,3) Avoiding multiple API calls:

**by_name or by_geocoord** API restrict the search based on the modes, though it can fulfil the first requirement

Route transit API returns connection with the transit stations(by train only) and distances as well, based on the arrival and departure coordinates,

https://transit.api.here.com/v3/route.json?app_id=xxxxxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxxx&modes=intercity_train,bus,light_rail&dep=41.9773,-87.9019&arr=41.8961,-87.6552&time=2019-06-24T07%3A30%3A00#

Comment: Thanks for that reply,

The only issue i see with this is specifying arrival coordinates.  The departure coordinates will be dynamically input into the query and i can maybe use Moment for the time but unsure what I would have to use for the arrival unless i was able to just specify a generic location in London for example but would this yield the same station results?

Thanks